# Operand type clash when using ORDER BY CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SELECT statement inside a stored procedure that, based on the value of a variable, produces a different ORDER BY result:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]

    @randomAnswers bit = 0

AS
    SELECT
        ab.answerID, -- int
        ab.someCol   -- nvarchar(max)
    FROM
        tbl_ABC ab 
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @randomAnswers = 1 THEN 
            NEWID()
        ELSE 
            ab.answerID
        END;
```

The error is

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

How do I overcome this?  On other sites I've seen very similar approaches without errors.
Thanks.

Comment: It won't produce an error if you make `answerID` to have type `uniqueidentifier`, but since it has, you can't do it this way. It it possible to create random `int` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your order by on two columns.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @RandomAnswers = 1 THEN NEWID() END,
         ab.answerID
```

First column will be null when `@RandomAnswers = 0` and that makes the second column the effective order by column.

Comment: Thanks.  If `@RandomAnswers = 0` will it just order by `answerID` then and ignore `NEWID()`?  I just can't quite see what's happening here...

Comment: @EvilDr Added more detail.

Comment: Ahh, so the ORDER BY part of the statement actually creates a NEWID column in the background?

Comment: Well, it is the case statement that is the first column in the order by clause. Then there is a comma followed by the second column. In the case when values in the first column are equal rows will be sorted by the second column.

Comment: This actually works amazingly well.  On playing around, I can get all sorts of randomness going on at different times, e.g. `ORDER BY
 fkID, someCol, CASE WHEN @random = 1 THEN NEWID() END, answerID`.  Fantastic, thank you very much - a real learning experience that one...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
    @randomAnswers bit = 0
AS
    SELECT ab.answerID,
           ab.someCol
    FROM tbl_ABC ab
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN @randomAnswers = 1 THEN CHECKSUM(NEWID()) ELSE ab.answerID END
```